# pattern search using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ab");  // Case 1
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("bab");  // Case 2
    Matcher m = p.matcher("abababa");
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.print(m.start());
    }
}
```

When I used **Case 1**, then output is **024** as expected. But, when I used **Case 2** then output is **1**, but I was expected **13**. So, anyone explain me, is there any exceptional rule in `regex`, which causes this output, if not. Then, why I'm getting this output.

Help appreciated !!

**Note :** Case 1 and Case 2 are independently used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match *consumes* the input, so the next match is found *after* the end of the previous match:

Position of "bab" matcher's pointer before each match would be:

1. `|abababa`
2. `abab|aba`

Answer (score 0):

For Case 2:

its because, after it search's for `bab`, it wouldn't consider the already searched char(b in this case at index 3) thus you get only 1.

```
Input:  abababa
Search for bab, 
 find's a match starting at index 1 and ending at index 3, next the search would start at index 4(aba)
```